# How do I load an EDMX schema file in Java with OLingo 4?

Tags: java, odata, edmx, olingo

I have a large edmx schema file that would be very inconvenient to manually re-create, one EntityType at a time, in Java using OLingo. While I'm not opposed to writing a loader of some kind, I wanted to make sure that OLingo 4 doesn't already provide this functionality.

I found an [article](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/Olingo_Tutorial_BasicRead_EDM.html) that shows how OLingo 2 can load this kind of information:

```
 @Override
 public Edm readMetadata(final InputStream inputStream, final boolean validate) 
    throws EntityProviderException {
    EdmProvider provider = new EdmxProvider().parse(inputStream, validate);
    return new EdmImplProv(provider);
 }
```

But I need to use version 4. I haven't found the same interfaces in the documentation for version 4, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, I found that I needed the [odata-server-core-ext](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.olingo/odata-server-core-ext) package and I could import `org.apache.olingo.server.core.MetadataParser`. Among other things, this class has a function called [`buildEdmProvider(Reader)`](https://github.com/apache/olingo-odata4/blob/fd8bfa33d485e6ea158025d468a009cd8bfc19ff/lib/server-core-ext/src/main/java/org/apache/olingo/server/core/MetadataParser.java#L164) which does the work of building a `SchemaBasedEdmProvider` for you.

Comment: Please note, that classes located in core package usually are not meant to be used and that their interface can change at any time.

Comment: @tbonk is there a way that doesn't involve the core package that you know of?

Comment: I think that it's not possible, unfortunately. i'm using that solution, too. But that's only a temporary solution. In the next step, I'm going to implement an EdmProvider and different kinds of processors that use annotated classes for schema generation and handling of CRUD operations, call of actions and functions.

Comment: @thbonk I figured that the only way around it would be to basically reimplement MetadataParser myself... Unfortunately, I didn't have time to do it. It's interesting how their v2 API exposed this kind of functionality, but not v4. I'll just keep the dependency version locked for now.

Comment: Do you mean loading and exposing an edmx schema or are you referring to the annotation processor in olingo-odata2. The annotation processor has more or less the status of a POC and has major performance flaws. E.g. filtering is done in memory by loading *all* records of an entity and then it does the filtering.

Comment: @thbonk I mean loading and exposing an edmx schema in v4

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to OLingo, you could also try odata-client: https://github.com/davidmoten/odata-client

I've not had a good chance to use it myself as unfortunately the web service I'm trying to connect to is OData 2, and odata-client only supports 4. However, it looked to have some neat features (including type safety and automatic/transparent paging).